# OpenCL with C, permission denied at run.sh

Tags: c, opencl

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "matmul.h"
#include "util.h"

#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_2_APIS
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK_ERROR(err)                                                       \
  if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {                                                     \
    printf("[%s:%d] OpenCL error %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, err);              \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                        \
  }

static cl_int err;
static cl_platform_id platform;
static cl_device_id device;
static cl_context context;
static cl_command_queue queue;
static cl_program program;
static cl_kernel kernel;
static cl_mem a_d, b_d, c_d;

void matmul(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, int M, int N, int K) {
  for (int m=0; m<M; m++) {
    for (int n=0; n<N; n++) {
        float acc = 0.0f;
        for (int k=0; k<K; k++) {
            acc += A[k*M + m] * B[n*K + k];
        }
        C[n*M + m] = acc;
    }
  }
}

static void print_platform_info(cl_platform_id platform) {
  size_t sz;
  char *buf;
  CHECK_ERROR(clGetPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 0, NULL, &sz));
  buf = (char *)malloc(sz);
  CHECK_ERROR(clGetPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sz, buf, NULL));
  printf("Detected OpenCL platform: %s\n", buf);
  free(buf);
}

static void print_device_info(cl_device_id device) {
  size_t sz;
  char *buf;
  CHECK_ERROR(clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 0, NULL, &sz));
  buf = (char *)malloc(sz);
  CHECK_ERROR(clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, sz, buf, NULL));
  printf("Detected OpenCL device: %s\n", buf);
  free(buf);
}

static cl_program create_and_build_program_with_source(cl_context context,
                                                       cl_device_id device,
                                                       const char *file_name) {
  FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open %s\n", file_name);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_t source_size = ftell(file);
  rewind(file);
  char *source_code = (char *)malloc(source_size + 1);
  size_t ntotal = 0;
  while (ntotal < source_size) {
    int nread = fread(source_code, sizeof(char), source_size, file);
    ntotal += nread;
  }
  source_code[source_size] = '\0';
  fclose(file);
  cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(
      context, 1, (const char **)&source_code, &source_size, &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  free(source_code);
  err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, "", NULL, NULL);
  if (err == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) {
    size_t log_size;
    CHECK_ERROR(clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0,
                                      NULL, &log_size));
    char *log = (char *)malloc(log_size + 1);
    CHECK_ERROR(clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                                      log_size, log, NULL));
    log[log_size] = 0;
    printf("Compile error:\n%s\n", log);
    free(log);
  }
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  return program;
}

void matmul_initialize(int M, int N, int K) {
  // Get OpenCL platform
  err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  print_platform_info(platform);

  // Get OpenCL device (only 1)
  err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  print_device_info(device);

  // Create OpenCL context
  context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);

  // Create OpenCL command queue
  queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);

  // Compile program from "kernel.cl"
  program = create_and_build_program_with_source(context, device, "kernel.cl");

  // Extract kernel from compiled program
  kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "sgemm", &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);

  // Create GPU buffers
  a_d = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, M * K * sizeof(float), NULL,
                       &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  b_d = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, K * N * sizeof(float), NULL,
                       &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
  c_d = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, M * N * sizeof(float), NULL,
                       &err);
  CHECK_ERROR(err);
}

void matmul_finalize() {
  clReleaseMemObject(a_d);
  clReleaseMemObject(b_d);
  clReleaseMemObject(c_d);
  clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
  clReleaseContext(context);
  clReleaseProgram(program);
  clReleaseKernel(kernel);
}
```

This one is the matmul.c,

```
#include "util.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

static double start_time[8];

void timer_init() { srand(time(NULL)); }

static double get_time() {
  struct timespec tv;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tv);
  return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_nsec * 1e-9;
}

void timer_start(int i) { start_time[i] = get_time(); }

double timer_stop(int i) { return get_time() - start_time[i]; }

void alloc_mat(float **m, int R, int S) {
  *m = (float *)aligned_alloc(32, sizeof(float) * R * S);
  if (*m == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate memory for mat.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
}

void rand_mat(float *m, int R, int S) {
  int N = R * S;
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    m[j] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX - 0.5;
  }
}

void zero_mat(float *m, int R, int S) {
  int N = R * S;
  memset(m, 0, sizeof(float) * N);
}

void print_mat(float *m, int M, int N) {
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      printf("%+.3f ", m[i * N + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void check_mat_mul(float *A, float *B, float *C, int M, int N, int K) {
  printf("Validating...\n");

  float *C_ans;
  alloc_mat(&C_ans, M, N);
  zero_mat(C_ans, M, N);
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        C_ans[i * N + j] += A[i * K + k] * B[k * N + j];
      }
    }
  }

  bool is_valid = true;
  int cnt = 0, thr = 10;
  float eps = 1e-3;
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      float c = C[i * N + j];
      float c_ans = C_ans[i * N + j];
      if (fabsf(c - c_ans) > eps &&
          (c_ans == 0 || fabsf((c - c_ans) / c_ans) > eps)) {
        ++cnt;
        if (cnt <= thr)
          printf("C[%d][%d] : correct_value = %f, your_value = %f\n", i, j,
                 c_ans, c);
        if (cnt == thr + 1)
          printf("Too many error, only first %d values are printed.\n", thr);
        is_valid = false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (is_valid) {
    printf("Result: VALID\n");
  } else {
    printf("Result: INVALID\n");
  }
}
```

This one is utils.c,

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "matmul.h"
#include "util.h"

static void print_help(const char *prog_name) {
  printf("Usage: %s [-pvh] [-n num_iterations] M N K\n", prog_name);
  printf("Options:\n");
  printf("     -p : print matrix. (default: off)\n");
  printf("     -v : validate matrix multiplication. (default: off)\n");
  printf("     -h : print this page.\n");
  printf("     -n : number of iterations (default: 1)\n");
  printf("      M : number of rows of matrix A and C. (default: 8)\n");
  printf("      N : number of columns of matrix B and C. (default: 8)\n");
  printf(
      "      K : number of columns of matrix A and rows of B. (default: 8)\n");
}

static bool print_data = false;
static bool validation = false;
static int M = 8;
static int N = 8;
static int K = 8;
static int num_iterations = 1;

static void parse_opt(int argc, char **argv) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "pvht:n:m:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'p':
      print_data = true;
      break;
    case 'v':
      validation = true;
      break;
    case 'n':
      num_iterations = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'h':
    default:
      print_help(argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
  for (int i = optind, j = 0; i < argc; ++i, ++j) {
    switch (j) {
    case 0:
      M = atoi(argv[i]);
      break;
    case 1:
      N = atoi(argv[i]);
      break;
    case 2:
      K = atoi(argv[i]);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("Options:\n");
  printf("  Problem size: M = %d, N = %d, K = %d\n", M, N, K);
  printf("  Number of iterations: %d\n", num_iterations);
  printf("  Print matrix: %s\n", print_data ? "on" : "off");
  printf("  Validation: %s\n", validation ? "on" : "off");
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  parse_opt(argc, argv);

  printf("Initializing... ");
  fflush(stdout);
  float *A, *B, *C;

  // Initialize random seed
  timer_init();

  // Allocate matrices
  alloc_mat(&A, M, K);
  alloc_mat(&B, K, N);
  alloc_mat(&C, M, N);

  // Set each element to a random value
  rand_mat(A, M, K);
  rand_mat(B, K, N);

  printf("done!\n");

  // Initialize OpenCL
  printf("Initializing OpenCL...\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  matmul_initialize(M, N, K);

  // Few warmup iterations
  zero_mat(C, M, N);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    matmul(A, B, C, M, N, K);
  }

  double elapsed_time_sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
    printf("Calculating...(iter=%d) ", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    zero_mat(C, M, N);

    timer_start(0);
    matmul(A, B, C, M, N, K);

    double elapsed_time = timer_stop(0);
    printf("%f sec\n", elapsed_time);
    elapsed_time_sum += elapsed_time;
  }

  if (print_data) {
    printf("MATRIX A:\n");
    print_mat(A, M, K);
    printf("MATRIX B:\n");
    print_mat(B, K, N);
    printf("MATRIX C:\n");
    print_mat(C, M, N);
  }

  // Finalize OpenCL
  matmul_finalize();

  if (validation) {
    check_mat_mul(A, B, C, M, N, K);
  }

  double elapsed_time_avg = elapsed_time_sum / num_iterations;
  printf("Avg. time: %f sec\n", elapsed_time_avg);
  printf("Avg. throughput: %f GFLOPS\n",
         2.0 * M * N * K / elapsed_time_avg / 1e9);

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the main.c

And I run this code by

```
#!/bin/bash

srun --nodes=1 --exclusive --partition=class1 --gres=gpu:4 ./main $@
```

at the GPU cluster server but it gaves me

bash: ./run_performance.sh: Permission denied

This error.

I think there is no problem on the access authority to the GPU.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

I am not sure but

```
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_2_APIS
```

This version problems seems the issue.

This is the GPU information about the server

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.8.88
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info cl_khr_external_semaphore cl_khr_external_memory cl_khr_external_semaphore_opaque_fd cl_khr_external_memory_opaque_fd
  Platform Host timer resolution                  0ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     NVIDIA TITAN RTX
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  520.61.05
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
```

Changing the version, and API version on the #define part of matmul.c

Comment: What are the permissions on ./run_performance.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `run_performance.sh` does not have execute file permissions. In Linux there is separate permissions for each file to read/write/execute, and by default the execute permission is turned off, to avoid accidential execution of files and potential harm to the system.

In your case, you want the file to be executable. To fix that, run:

```bash
chmod +x run_performance.sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... learn a lot from here